# Copy active class from one div to another div with a corresponding data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle

Is there a way to toggle the class `selected` that is currently set on the button in `.ProductItem-gallery-slides` to the corresponding button in `.ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails` with the same `data` attribute?

```html
<div class="ProductItem-gallery-scroll">
  <div class="ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails">
    <button class="ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails-item" data-thumbnail-index="1"> Hello 1 </button>
    <button class="ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails-item" data-thumbnail-index="2"> Hello 2 </button>
    <button class="ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails-item" data-thumbnail-index="3"> Hello 3 </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ProductItem-gallery-slides" data-animation-role="image" data-product-gallery="slides">
  <button class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item selected" data-slide-index="1"> Good bye 1</button>
  <button class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item" data-slide-index="2">Good bye 2</button>
  <button class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item" data-slide-index="3">Good bye 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes there is. Please provide your attempt within the question so that we can help you to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I agree with Rory - I suspect there is no example code so I hope the following is what you're after:

```
$('.ProductItem-gallery-thumbnails-item').on('click',function(){
    $('.ProductItem-gallery-slides-item').removeClass('selected');
    
    $('.ProductItem-gallery-slides-item[data-slide-index="'+$(this).data('thumbnail-index')+'"]').addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: Correct, there was no code because this was being created from scratch. Thank you so much for the assistance.